Persistent MSFT graph API 500 response with "Unable to get write stream for mac attachment
We are seeing this issue for a few tenants. We are doing GET message graph api calls followed by $expand attachments. For a handful of exchange emails, we see Graph return
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error with Unable to get write stream for mac attachment message. Also seen if we try to download attachments one at a time, using attachment IDs.
This is a persistent error and we can never download these attachments. Can someone please help us shed some light on what this issue is? Does it have anything to do with attachments uploaded via Mac OS? There is no documentation on this error from MSFT. Would really appreciate some help!

Could you confirm that the exception is happening for attachments uploaded from Mac OS?  How did you upload those messages?

Thanks, we don't know if these were uploaded from Mac OS, as they were uploaded by our customers. We are trying to back up their mailboxes using graph API and running into this error for a few attachments.
